# FFImageLoading: Svg not loading

Tags: c#, svg, xamarin, ffimageloading

I try to load svg image with `FFImageLoading` library, but i see empty white image.

Code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CrewManagement"
         x:Class="CrewManagement.MainPage"            
         xmlns:abstractions="clr-namespace:ExtendedCells.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ExtendedCells.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions"
         xmlns:ffimageloadingsvg="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Svg.Forms"
         >

<ContentPage.Content>
<ffimageloadingsvg:SvgCachedImage WidthRequest="200" HeightRequest="200" Source="http://loremflickr.com/600/600/nature?filename=simple.svg"/>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Here image:  [image: white image]

Comment: are you using the right version of the pkg?  See https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/579

Comment: You are missing the closing tag : </ContentPage>

Comment: i use Svg.Forms v2.2.10-pre-391